# Python: How to find proper subsets from large sets without getting Memory Error?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, iterator, generator

I am trying to get proper subsets of integers using the following code:

```
set1 = [9,10]
set2 = [9, 10, 23, 26, 27, 28, 31, 32, 33, 36, 38, 41, 43, 45, 46]

allsubsets = set(chain.from_iterable(combinations(set2, ss) for ss in range(len(set1)+1, len(set2))))
```

However, when the size of set2 is greater than 30 I get a memory error in the allsubsets line. I want to make this code efficient without allocating too much memory.

Since, **itertools combinations** is already a generator function it is fast and memory efficient. I understand that while saving it into a set the memory error occurs. I tried using `itertools.islice()` to split the iterable into multiple sets and do the downstream operations. However, even then I have to save the iterator into a list or set. Otherwise the iterator is lost after first slicing.

Can you please suggest on how to get proper subsets from large sets without memory error ?

**UPDATE:** I realized that this approach will not work if we have large list of subsets. It will result in Memory error especially if we want downstream operations on them. It will also be computationally expensive in terms of both runtime and memory. The best thing is to redesign the algorithm or code in a way that we don't have to get such large list of subsets. The way you redesign depends on what results you want from your code.

Comment: You're asking for `allsubsets` to be a very very large set. Is that not what you want? If not you'll need to explain or show what you want to do with these subsets.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yes you are right. It will be a very very large set. I want all possible combinations of subsets of size 3 to be extracted from ```set2``` and that should also have items of ```set1``` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't your 'downstream operations' essentially consist of iterating over the proper subsets and doing something with them? If so, just skip the part where you try to convert to a set. You can iterate over the `itertools.chain` object (a generator), like so:

```
set1 = [9,10]
set2 = [9, 10, 23, 26, 27, 28, 31, 32, 33, 36, 38, 41, 43, 45, 46]
allsubsets = chain.from_iterable(combinations(set2, ss) for ss in range(len(set1)+1, len(set2)))
for s in allsubsets:
    print(s)
```

Just replace the `print(s)` part with whatever you need to do.

`set1` and `set2` can then be as big as you like and you'll never run into memory issues. Of course, your program may still take a very long time to execute if you're iterating over many many values.

Comment: yes I already tried this option. Even while looping over the ```allsubsets``` I ran into a Memory Error because I was filtering the ```allsubsets``` to get the proper sets with this check: ```  if set(set1).issubset(s) ```  inside the for loop. I need to make sure that only the subsets having ```set1``` in the ```allsubsets``` are selected.